# How can I use nz on a table field in a filter

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to use nz on a table field in a filter on a form, however the filter is returning 0 results.

I originally tried doing this;

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "UCase([DELV_ADDR]) like '%" & UCase(Nz(Me.delv_txt,"""")) & "%'"
```

but this only returns entries that don't have blank addresses. I also tried

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "UCase([DELV_ADDR]) like '%" & UCase(Me.delv_txt) & "%' and isNull(Me.delv_txt)"
```

but predictably it returned addresses that matched my criteria and all null addresses

This code is what I've ended up with but it's still not working.

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "UCase(Nz([DELV_ADDR], """")) like '%" & UCase(Nz(Me.delv_txt,"""")) & "%'"
```

This filter doesn't return any results at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: MS Access uses the `*` character for wildcards with the LIKE operator. I would see if changing `%` to `*` solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access uses the * character for wildcards with the LIKE operator.

Change the `%` wildcards to `*` and it will return the results as expected:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter "", "UCase(Nz([DELV_ADDR], """")) like '*" & UCase(Nz(Me.delv_txt,"""")) & "*'"
```